# Writing Function to find non-numbers

Tags: r, function

I have to modify the following function so that indices of `NA` are not returned:

```
findNonNumbers <- function(z) {
  return(which(is.na(as.numeric(z))))
}
```

I know this question is super basic, but I'm new to R and struggling with this.

Comment: You probably want `which(is.na(as.numeric(z)) & !is.na(z))` - But please give an example so that it is more clear what you are looking for.

Comment: This worked. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Ok - I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply exclude those indices that are `NA` in the input vector:

```
findNonNumbers <- function(z) {
  return(which(is.na(as.numeric(z)) & !is.na(z)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too!

```
findNonNumbers <- function(z) {
  return(which(!is.na(as.numeric(z))))
}
```